# Count all occurances of every value in a column

Tags: mysql

I hope my problem can be understood ...
How can I get the sum of rows for every value that can be found within a column for a certain foreign key?

Example:

[image]

Here I want to count the occurance of every value in the column "value" where the foreign key is 1.

So the example result would be like : 3 (3x "2") and 2 (2x "5")

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very simple [group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) problem. There are a number of aggregation functions in MySQL and all other SQL dialects. Some vary from dialect to dialect so be sure to read [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/func-op-summary-ref.html) to see if something exists to fit your use case.

In your particular case, you want to group by value and foreign key (e.g. value = 2 and foreign key = 1 is a group, value = 5 and foreign key = 1 is a different group), counting the values in each group:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(value) AS count,
  value,
  foreign_key
FROM my_table
GROUP BY value, foreign_key
```

Good luck!

**EDIT:**

I read from this portion of the original question:

```
3 (3x "2") and 2 (2x "5")
```

That the desired output would be 6 (3 x 2) and 10 (2 x 5). I see now the desired output was likely 3 (the count of 2's) and 2 (the count of 5's) in which case the correct query would be the edited one above.

Comment: You want to `COUNT` not `SUM`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(value) AS nb_value, value, `foreign key`  
FROM table_name
WHERE `foreign key`=1
GROUP BY value, `foreign key`;
```

**"nb_values"** : an alias for the result. it optional but it makes thing a bit clearer.
**"table_name"**: the name of the table you a pulling the data from.

That should output the number of values where 1 as the id/key from the table called table_name.

For further explanation see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp).

Comment: You are missing a `GROUP BY` clause. Your query will return simply 1, the count of rows with the ID 1.

Comment: thank you but I actually need to know the count of every distinct value in the column. As far as I understand your suggestion it will just return the count of distinct values in that column (basically it returns just 1 value but i need n values were n is the amount of diffrent values in that column)

Comment: @HansGerber I've added the DISTINCT clause so each value will be counted only once.

Comment: This still not correct for several reasons. COUNT DISTINCT will not count the number of occurances within a group, it counts the number DISTINCT occurances within a group. Were Hans to execute your query, he would get an answer of 1 distinct value within each group, whether each group had 1 or 100 occurances. A second problem is that it doesn't scale if Hans wants to know the count for more than one foreign key.

Comment: Thanks lot for your time and critics. I've [tested](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47374/10/0) my query an updated my answer. Even though the asker has passed to something else.  I'm not sure I understand the _scale_ part though.